# primefaces datatable and browser back button

Tags: jsf, primefaces

I have a search page for which I am using the Primefaces datatable and the backingbean scope is Viewscope. For the searchresults I am using the primefaces p:commandLink so when I click on the commandlink I will navigate to details page of that link. When I click on the browser back button from the details page it is navigating to the search page but the datatable is not displayed. 
I need the datatable to be displayed with the results it has previously when I click on the browser back button from the details page.

Checked in the forums but could not find any solution for it. Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Use GET instead of POST and turn off browser caching.

Comment: I can use the h:link since it is GET request but I have outcome generated from the backingbean method to which, the page need to be navigated. But from h:link I can not invoke the backing bean action method. Could anyone has an idea how can we invoke a backing bean action method from h:link.